# Behavior of \mathcal and \mathscr in STIX 2.0.0

Tags: mathcal, stix

I recently installed STIX 2.0.0 and remarked that \mathcal and \mathscr give the same result (calligraphic letters). A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
$$
\mathcal{A} \mathscr{A}
$$
\end{document}
```

But if I add the option

```
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=01]{STIX Two Math}
```

they again give the same result, this time calligraphic letters with "roundhand style".

Is it the normal behavior of these commands in STIX 2? Is there a way to have the first kind on \mathcal and the second "roundhand style" one on \mathscr?

Answer (score 12):

Define a font for the `\mathscr` range, see section 5.4.2 “Calligraphic vs. Script variants”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={scr,bfscr},StylisticSet=01]

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{A}\mathcal{B}\mathcal{C}$

$\mathscr{A}\mathscr{B}\mathscr{C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the `unicode-math` version of the legacy method

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
```

so doing `\mathscr{A}` just chooses the glyph based on a math code, not going through `\mathchoice` in a text mode box where an altogether different math version is set up.

Comment: It works! For futur reference to this answer: the document you are refering to is the unicode-math package documentation section 5.4.2 “Calligraphic vs. Script variants” that can be found on the CTAN page of the package.

Answer (score 5):

`\mathcal` and `\mathscr` (actually, `\symcal` and `\symscr`, and the former two commands are just aliases) point to the same Unicode ranges, as it can be seen from the `unicode-math.sty`:

```
\usv_set:nnn {scr} {Latin}{"1D49C}
\usv_set:nnn {cal} {Latin}{"1D49C}
```

So they aren't supposed to look differently.

If you want them to, then you'll have to use different math *versions*. The problem with this approach is that you cannot switch math versions inside a formula, but for `\mathscr` it shouldn't be a big problem. Just put the letters into a box like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=script,StylisticSet=1]

\renewcommand{\mathscr}[1]{{\text{\mathversion{script}$\symscr{#1}$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{A} \mathscr{A} \mathcal{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

I've also replaced `$$ ... $$` by `\[ ... \]` as the latter behave better in LaTeX code (for example, they honor the `fleqn` documentclass option).