A proper math font
The question
I would like to have a math font that fulfills all of the following requirements:

\mathbb looks as close as possible to LaTeX's default math font

\mathcal is only slightly curved

\mathscr is very strongly curved

It has a reasonable implementation of \mathbb{0} and \mathbb{1}


More precisely, I am just looking for some kind of setup where the output is as close as possible to the fonts in the first screenshot except for the last column. How can I achieve this?
I have compiled the following test files:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm,paperwidth=30cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
& \verb_\mathcal_
& \verb_\mathscr_
& \verb_\mathbb_
& \verb_\mathbb_ \\
default
& {$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathbb{01}$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=35cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
& \verb_\mathcal_
& \verb_\mathscr_
& \verb_\mathbb_
& \verb_\mathbb_ \\
Latin Modern Math
& {\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}$\mathbb{01}$} \\
New Computer Modern Math
& {\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}$\mathbb{01}$} \\
XITS Math
& {\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mathbb{01}$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


My problems
The only problem with the "default" math font is that (4.) is not fulfilled, meaning that there is no reasonable implementation of \mathbb{0} and \mathbb{1}. Properties (1.), (2.) and (3.) are fulfilled.
None of the "Latin Modern Math", "New Computer Modern Math" or "XITS Math" math fonts fulfill both (2.) and (3.) since in them the styles \mathcal and \mathscr are equivalent. Of those three, only "New Computer Modern Math" fulfills property (1.). They all fulfill (4.).
Links
What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?
Which OpenType Math fonts are available?

@DavidCarlisle I've specificed the question. All I really want is a setup where the output is as close as possible to the output of the first screenshot except for the last column.


Your first example appears to be for pdftex with 8 bit fonts so it is not "a math font":  each of the fonts you are selecting is separate and may be separately chosen there are several double struck math fonts that include digits.
Here I use bbold
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm,paperwidth=30cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,bbold}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
& \verb_\mathcal_
& \verb_\mathscr_
& \verb_\mathbb_
& \verb_\mathbb_ \\
default
& {$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathbb{01}$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Many of the OpenType Math fonts have both styles of script but as they are overlayed on to the same Unicode code points, you have to work a bit harder to separate them, one easy (but not necessarily the most efficient) way is shown below

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=3cm,paperwidth=30cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361711/1090
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=script,StylisticSet=1]

\renewcommand{\mathscr}[1]{{\text{\mathversion{script}$\symscr{#1}$}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
& \verb_\symcal_
& \verb_\symscr_
& \verb_\symbb_
& \verb_\symbb_ \\
default
& {$\symcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\symbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$}
& {$\symbb{01}$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


Is it possible to use bbold only for \mathbb{0} and \mathbb{1}?

@Smiley1000 yes,  bbold.sty is only 3 lines of code, copy to the preamble and change the last one to be \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbx}{U}{bbold}{m}{n} then use \mathbbx{0}  not \mathbb{0}

Thanks, that works perfectly for me! Could you add this to the body of the answer?
